# Is it possible to use RStudio IDE on an AWS SageMaker instance

Tags: r, rstudio, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to use the RStudio IDE to R on an Amazon SageMaker instance. What I have tried so far is to run the following docker command:

```
docker run --rm -p 8787:8787 rocker/verse
```

which appears to work successfully. What I would then do when running that command from my local computer is go to `http://localhost:8787` where I would be able to login and find a fully functional RStudio IDE within my browser.

However, this is obviously not possible from within SageMaker as there is no `localhost` to visit.

Is there some way I can direct my browser to capture the output to port 8787 from the SageMaker instance?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RStudio is now available as a managed service in SageMaker. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/rstudio.html

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for using Amazon SageMaker!

SageMaker Notebook Instance do not support RStudio IDE but you can use R kernel already installed on SageMaker Notebook Instance.

Please checkout our blog post on using R in Amazon SageMaker [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/using-r-with-amazon-sagemaker/) .

We are always re-evaluating our backlog of features based on customer requests, so we appreciate the feedback on this feature.

Thanks,

Neelam